# ios 10 youtube iframe not playing

Tags: html, ios, iphone, iframe, autoplay

I'm using the following iframe in my HTML code:

```
        <iframe src="<iframeurl>">?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

On iPhone with iOS10 this doesn't autoplay. I'm getting the red play button and stuff. On windows chrome and others all works fine autoplay starts correctly. But not with the iphone.

Is there anything I could do in javascript or by manipulating the URL to make this autoplay? I'm aware that Apple used to disallow autoplay before iOS10 so maybe I'm doing something wrong here..

Comment: Any workaround is appreciated, I've been scounting the web for some time and I couldn't find anything to actually work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the play trigger to onClick and then execute call the click event from an AJAX response.

Should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 5):

You're experiencing this because Apple doesn't allow embedded media to play automatically — the user always initiates playback.

This is mentioned in [YouTube's IFrame Player API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations) as well. And no, I don't think you can and should override this since that is a bad practice.

Comment: And why is that a bad practice?

Comment: Because it causes traffic and traffic is expensive on mobilde devices.
If the user want to see the video he can click the button.

Can you explaine what you want to do and why it is neccessary to use autoplay.

Comment: I see, so traffic is expensive but only on Apple devices.. If my clients want this and are paying for it, this reason is enough. It's for the header background of a landing page. Html5 doesn't work either on specific mobile devices, showing an image instead of video only for mobile is also not desired by clients, etc.

Comment: @ MFGSparka By the way, youtube in the browser does this, so you say that it's bad practice for normal users and it's good practice for youtube?

Comment: Its probably a bad practice because it was not a feature intended by the platform owner's (Apple).  Still just an opinion, but if you find a workaround, its not a guaranteed feature that will work in the long run. (i.e. the exploit might work for iOS 10, but iOS 11 would break it).  Apple tends to be more a strong user advocate than most.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that iOS prevents any video from autoplaying (at least not so since iOS 10), but it is unmuted videos that are prevented from playing without user interaction. So if you embed a YouTube video with `muted=1` appended to the URL, autoplay works again.

P.S. the `muted` parameter is **not documented** for the YouTube embedded players. It is nowhere to be found in the official doc: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters. Yet it has been working for quite a while. If you worry it may not work someday, you can take the programmatic approach via the iframe API: first mute the video and then play it when the `ready` event is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

putting this in config.xml worked for me:
`<allow-navigation href="*://*youtube.com" />`